# Overriding get_queryset, but get empty result set

Tags: django, django-queryset

So I have a database of books, and I want to search it based on filters and keywords so I've overridden the get_queryset method in my BookSearch view:

```
  class BookSearch(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductDetailViewSerializer
    model = ProductDetailView 

    def get_queryset(self):
      queryset = None
      categories = self.kwargs['categories'].rstrip()    
      keywords = self.kwargs['keywords'].rstrip()
      if isinstance(categories, str) and isinstance(keywords, str):
        book_filter = BookFilter(categories)
        sql = self.get_sql(categories, keywords, book_filter)
        queryset = ProductDetailView.objects.filter(
                      id__in=RawSQL(sql, book_filter.params)
                   )
        message = f"{queryset.query}"
        log_to_file('BookSearch.log', 'BookSearch.get_queryset', message)
        return queryset
```

That log_to_file call logs the query that django uses, which I've abbreviated here
but is as follows:

```
   SELECT `jester_productdetailview`.`id`, 
             `jester_productdetailview`.`isbn`, 
             `jester_productdetailview`.`title`  
     FROM `jester_productdetailview` 
    WHERE `jester_productdetailview`.`id` IN (
      select id from jester_productdetailview   
       where ( authors like '%Beatrix%' or 
               illustrators like '%Beatrix%' or 
               title like '%Beatrix%' ) ) 
    ORDER BY `jester_productdetailview`.`title` ASC
```

If I run that query in my database manually, I get 186 rows:

```
   '119371','9780723259572','A Beatrix Potter Treasury'
   '130754','9780241293348','A Christmas Wish'
   '117336','9780241358740','A Pumpkin for Peter' ...
```

To get the query above, I call the view through the API, yet by the time the queryset is returned, there are no results ???

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book-search/{"filter"](http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book-search/%7B%22filter%22): "all"}/Beatrix/
returns []

Answer (score 0):

You are returning queryset only within the if condition only. By default, the function is sending None. Return the queryset outside the if condition as well.